# Is there any single name for this type of sport which look like exercise?

Tags: image-identification

I saw this scene in ***Baywatch (2017)*** movie, Matt Brody moving from place to another by this sticks by putting into holes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the show *American Ninja Warrior* (an extreme-fitness competition TV reality show), that is referred to as **[*monkey pegs*](https://www.google.com/search?q=monkey%20pegs%20american%20ninja%20warrior&client=ubuntu&hs=ArH&channel=fs&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvia2nr-LVAhVl64MKHaG5BecQsAQILg&biw=1784&bih=951)**.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard "peg board" (sometimes spelled "pegboard") and "peg wall". In your case, you might say it's a **horizontal** one.

Here are some links that use these terms:

- [American Ninja Warrior Training- Peg Wall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm62iOiWDCo)
- [Extreme Peg Wall Climbing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzAp7HrxR2k)
- [Force12 Peg board climb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbjKPJVrKUM)
- [The Pegboard: What's your technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOu9yFIeTEo)